# Unable to expand ListItem for a drive item when using Delta Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I am trying to access a custom column in SharePoint using the graph APIs delta query.

I am using `/sites/{siteId}/drive/{driveId}/delta?expand=listItem&token=deltaToken` but I am not getting the expected properties of the file in the response.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `/sites/{siteId}/drive/{driveId}/delta?expand=listItem(select=*,fields/CustomColumnName)&token=deltaToken` , See if this query works for you.

Comment: Nope didn't work out. Got "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Found a path with multiple navigation properties or a bad complex property path in a select clause. Please reword your query such that each level of select or expand only contains either TypeSegments or Properties." error message

Answer (score 0):

When using the Microsoft Graph API's delta query to retrieve changes in a SharePoint drive, you can expand the listItem property to include additional properties of the file in the response. However, custom columns (also known as site columns or custom metadata) are not included by default in the listItem property.

To include custom columns in the response, you need to explicitly specify the custom column names in the $select query parameter. Here's an example:

```
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/{driveId}/delta?expand=listItem($select=CustomColumn1,CustomColumn2)&token=deltaToken
```